# Terraform & AWS CodePipeline - Dynamically define actions on a stage

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline

I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I'd ask to check first.

I have a `CodePipeline` defined in `terraform`, with a single `Stage` that has multiple actions.

The `Stage` is pulling code from `CodeCommit`, and each action defines what repositories I want to use in the `Pipeline`.

I'd like to create a variable that has a list of the `CodeCommit` repository names, and then dynamically create an action for each repository in that list.

Is that possible with `terraform`? I know you can use `count` to achieve this normally, but I think that's only at a resource level?

Code snippet is below:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "Test" {
  name     = "Test"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.Test.arn}"

  "artifact_store" {
    location = "${aws_s3_bucket.Test.bucket}"
    type     = "S3"
  }

  "stage" {
    name = "Source"

    ####LOOP OVER EACH ITEM IN LIST###
    "action" {
        ...
    }
  }

  stage {
    name = "Build"

    ...

    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

Getting an error with this as the trigger for the null resource at the moment. I've tried a few different variations of this as well:

```
resource "null_resource" "CodePipeline" {
  count = "${length(var.repositories)}"

  triggers {
    action = {
      category         = "Source"
      name             = "Repository-${element(keys(var.repositories), count.index)}"
      owner            = "AWS"
      provider         = "CodeCommit"
      version          = "1"
      output_artifacts = ["Repository-${element(keys(var.repositories), count.index)}"]

      configuration {
        RepositoryName = "${element(keys(var.repositories), count.index)}"
        BranchName     = "${lookup(var.repositories, element(keys(var.repositories) ,count.index))}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use null_resources for this and pass a list of actions in the stage. like this

```
resource "null_resource" "actions" {
    count = length(<repo_list_var>)
    triggers {
       #### ACTION ITEMS ###
       ...........
    }
}

resource "aws_codepipeline" "Test" {
    name     = "Test"
    role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.Test.arn}"

    "artifact_store" {
        location = "${aws_s3_bucket.Test.bucket}"
        type     = "S3"
    }

    "stage" {
       name = "Source"
       action = null_resource.actions.*.triggers
    }

    stage {
        name = "Build"

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I'm struggling with the syntax of `#### ACTION ITEMS ###`. Do you have an example of what this should be?

Comment: I think I'm having an issue because my action requires a `configuration` map inside of it, and thus getting this error when trying to run `triggers (configuration): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]map[string]interface {}'`

Comment: Can you share, what are you adding for #### ACTION ITEMS ### ?

Comment: Sure, edited the original post with it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your issue seems to be related to the way you are treating configurations.  Configurations are part of actions, so if you are going to iterate through configuration, you actually need to iterate through the actions.  Your count index needs to on the action not the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

My most recent success with a Dynamic Stage in a Codepipeline has been leveraging a map variable and creating the entire pipeline as a dynamic resource.

Here is an example of the resource:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "codepipeline" {
  for_each = var.code_pipeline
  name     = "${local.name_prefix}-${var.AppName}"
  role_arn = each.value["code_pipeline_role_arn"]

  tags = {
    Pipeline_Key = each.key
  }

  artifact_store {
    type     = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? "" : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "type", "S3")
    location = lookup(each.value, "artifact_store", null) == null ? null : lookup(each.value.artifact_store, "artifact_bucket", null)
  }

  dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = lookup(each.value, "stages", {})
    iterator = stage
    content {
      name = lookup(stage.value, "name")
      dynamic "action" {
        for_each = lookup(stage.value, "actions", {}) //[stage.key]
        iterator = action
        content {
          name             = action.value["name"]
          category         = action.value["category"]
          owner            = action.value["owner"]
          provider         = action.value["provider"]
          version          = action.value["version"]
          run_order        = action.value["run_order"]
          input_artifacts  = lookup(action.value, "input_artifacts", null)
          output_artifacts = lookup(action.value, "output_artifacts", null)
          configuration    = action.value["configuration"]
          namespace        = lookup(action.value, "namespace", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the full working sample [here](https://github.com/cwnit/toolkits/tree/master/collections/terraform/aws/aws-codepipeline/dynamic-pipeline)

You can see that the stages are dynamic and the actions needed to create the pipeline.  Also, this accounts for the EnvironmentVariables and allows them to be dynamic.