# AWS Codepipeline with Terraform - How to dynamically create stages

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline, terraform0.12+

I designed an AWS codepipeline module using terraform module, I have multiple actual codepipelines using the codepipeline module. I use module as design pattern because all the codepipelines look similar, except that some of the codepipelines need approval stages, some do not need. How do I design the codepipeline module approval stages so that the actual codepipelines can be created based on different needs?

I tried to use count = 0 or 1 to control the stage but it does not work because the stage is not resource-level. Is there any tricky way or workaround?

I feel this link asked the similar question but I cannot figure out what is the answer:
[Terraform & AWS CodePipeline - Dynamically define actions on a stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280419/terraform-aws-codepipeline-dynamically-define-actions-on-a-stage)

Here is my codepipeline terraform module:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "dev" {
  name     = "my_codepipeline"
  role_arn = ...
  ...
  stage {
    name = "Source"
    ...
  }
  stage {
    name = "test"
    ...
  }
  stage {
    # count = 0 # or 1. it does not work
    name = "Approval"
    action {
      name     = "Approval"
      owner    = "AWS"
      category = "Approval"
      provider = "Manual"
      version  = "1"

      configuration {
        NotificationArn    = "..."
        CustomData         = "..."
        ExternalEntityLink = "..."
      }
    }
  }
  stage {
    name = "prod"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To dynamically add a stage (and not just an action) you could do the following:

```
dynamic "stage" {
   for_each = var.production_approval ? [1] : []
   content {
     name = "Approve"
     action {
       configuration = {
         NotificationArn = var.approve_sns_arn
         CustomData      = var.approve_comment
       }
       name     = "Production-Approval"
       category = "Approval"
       owner    = "AWS"
       provider = "Manual"
       version  = "1"
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: A link to the associated reference documents on this technic would strengthen your answer.

Comment: Is there a way  to create 2 stages in one dynamic block

Answer (score 1):

When going through your use case, I have the feeling that it is very suitable with new terraform feature in v0.12.x

Below is a sample on how to use `for_each` to set dynamic target regions, you should be fine to do the same for stages.

```
  dynamic "target_region" {
    for_each = var.target_image_regions
    content {
      name                   = target_region.value
      regional_replica_count = 1
    }
  }
```

let me know if this works for you or not.

Reference: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-terraform-0-12

Comment: This answer would be improved with an example that directly solves the specific question rather than a generic `for_each` example.

Comment: Thanks @BMW. I guess I should set dynamic "approval_stage" {for each = var.enable_approval_stage", ...} and the content is like content {name = ..., action {approval's action} but I still do not understand how to control whether to create approval_stage or not create approval_stage. in which case approval_stage will not be created? Can you show me an example? Thanks,

Comment: these variables `enable_approval_stage` can be set via terraform variable dynamically, such as `TF_VAR_enable_approval_stage=0 terraform apply`  So you can change these setting on-fly

Comment: Thanks @BMW, finally I decide not to control Approval stage. the AWS support said they do not have command to enable/disable a stage within a CodePipeline. so I do not believe terraform can set that either. I believe your approach works for other resource but not codepipeline. But Thank you very much for answering me.

Answer (score 1):

I figured that you can get this working in Terraform 0.12+ as BMW said, but only if you have number of block greater than 0.

```
At least 1 "action" blocks are required.
```

Unfortunately, my (and your) use case required 0/1 actions depending on the environment so we have to manage it manually for a while.

Cheers.

```
dynamic "action" {
  for_each = local.production_approval # e.g. [] || [true]  
  content {
    category         = "Approval"
    configuration    = {}
    input_artifacts  = []
    name             = "Production-Approval"
    output_artifacts = []
    owner            = "AWS"
    provider         = "Manual"
    run_order        = 1
    version          = "1"
  }
}
```